# Why the context.slots in the Vue setup() function has an empty object?

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-slot

Accordingly to this [Issue](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/issues/84) it should work with the current version v3.2.x.

**But it doesn't.**

Here is the playground:

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;

const myComponent = {
  template: '#my-component',
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    console.log(slots)
  }
}

const App = {
  components: { 
    myComponent
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">  
  <my-component>Default
  <template #footer>Footer</template>
  </my-component>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="my-component">
<div>
  <slot></slot>
  <hr/>
  <slot name="footer"></slot>
</div>
</script>
```

Comment: Don't `JSON.stringify(slots)`. Just log it directly `console.log(slots)`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks. But now the question is why?

Comment: I'm not sure but it will fall into one of these cases listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description). It will take much time to find the exact reason. So, if you really care about it, you have to dive into Vue source code to find it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was provided by Duannx.

With `console.log(slots)` they are listed correctly.

```
{
  "footer": (...n)=>{o._d&&Tr(-1);const r=hn(t);let s;try{s=e(...n)}finally{hn(r),o._d&&Tr(1)}return s},
  "default": (...n)=>{o._d&&Tr(-1);const r=hn(t);let s;try{s=e(...n)}finally{hn(r),o._d&&Tr(1)}return s}
}
```

### Explanation

JSON.stringify doesn't show the slots since they are functions.
Here is the explanation from the MDN Docs [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

`undefined`, `Function`, and `Symbol` values are not valid JSON values. If any such values are encountered during conversion, they are either omitted (when found in an object) or changed to `null` (when found in an array). `JSON.stringify()` can return undefined when passing in "pure" values like `JSON.stringify(() => {})` or `JSON.stringify(undefined)`.

### Example

```js
console.log("JSON.stringify(() => {}): " + JSON.stringify(() => {}));

console.log(JSON.stringify({ "func": function () {}, "lmbd": () => {} }))
```